# Best practice to build Spring boot REST api + static content + mobile client and secure it all together

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

For a long time I write using **spring boot** with all it's stack and all that time I thought I was good on with it, until I came to secure my REST api for mobile clients and static content.

Long story short, I have one spring boot application which has REST api endpoints for both components/clients:

1. **WEB application** (admin dashboard to manage a shop) written in angular which bundles into folder located in **src/main/resources/static** --- pretty common way to build such kind of app, just several bundled static files... So in this case spring also serves as a web server to return bundled WEB app when someone hits root path **/**
2. **Mobile client** is totally separate application written in **ionic 4** -- at first glance nothing tricky...

**The devil is in the <s>detail</s> security config...**

So, for the web application I use pretty simple mechanism to secure REST endpoints like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Set "remember me" expiration date to a week.
        final int rememberMeExpiration = 86400 * 7;

        http.csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage(EndpointPath.SIGN_IN)
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl(SIGN_OUT)
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(restLogoutSuccessHandler)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(GET, EndpointPath.PRODUCTS).authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(GET, EndpointPath.SYNCHRONIZE_PRODUCT).authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(POST, EndpointPath.PRODUCT).hasAnyAuthority(STORE_OWNER.name(), APPLICATION_ADMIN.name())
                    .antMatchers(GET, EndpointPath.PRODUCT + "/**/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(GET, EndpointPath.TOKEN_EXPIRED).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .rememberMe()
                    .key("rem-me-key")
                    .rememberMeParameter("rememberMe")
                    .rememberMeCookieName("remember_me_token")
                    .tokenValiditySeconds(rememberMeExpiration)
                    .alwaysRemember(true);
}
```

}

... the above approach works fine for the web app and it's based on **jsessionid cookie** but when it comes to the mobile client I need to do extra stuff, to deal with CORS and so on.

#### QUESTION 1

Is it good to create a separate path for mobile client related REST api endpoints like **api/**?

#### QUESTION 2

To deal with CORS for mobile client I had to deal with it's configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    class CORSConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/**").allowCredentials(true);
                }
            };
       }
   }
```

... I read that the **.allowCredentials(true);** is not good to make the auth work via JSESSIONID for mobile clients as well... so what comes to my mind is configure OAUTH 2 + JWT to make it work for mobile client in a better way.

The question: is it possible to have **WebSecurity** as I have for web app and at the same time configure OAUTH 2 for mobile clients?

#### QUESTION 3

Maybe some one could provide advices on architecture or general rules when we have different http clients like self served web app and mobile clients?

Comment: You can have seperate request headers for both clients and based on that category you can achieve it.

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 that makes sense and the configuration for the headers should be in CORSConfiguration?

Comment: Cors is browser specific you don't need to do any cors config for your mobile client.